# Get some set of values in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, join

I have a query, in this query I need to get a number of classes (class count) in each district. In here it comes only those who have classes. So I need to show the district's it doesn't have a classes as well.

My `District` table consist 25 values. and my class coverage table has 5 values to 3 districts. I need to show all the districts.

[image: C#]

Code

```
SELECT 
    CC.DistrictId, D.DistrictName,
    COUNT(D.DistrictId) AS DistrictCount
FROM
    TBL_T_ClassCoverage CC
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[TBL_M_District] D ON CC.DistrictId = D.DistrictId
WHERE 
    CC.IsActive = 1 
GROUP BY
    CC.DistrictId, D.DistrictName
ORDER BY
    DistrictId ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join your tables the other way, from districts to classes, to ensure that all district values are in the output:

```
  SELECT D.DistrictId, D.DistrictName, COUNT(CC.DistrictId) AS DistrictCount
  FROM [dbo].[TBL_M_District] D
  LEFT JOIN TBL_T_ClassCoverage CC
  ON CC.DistrictId = D.DistrictId AND CC.IsActive = 1 
  GROUP BY D.DistrictId, D.DistrictName
  ORDER BY D.DistrictId ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need `right join` not `left join` here.

```
SELECT CC.DistrictId, D.DistrictName, Count(D.DistrictId) AS DistrictCount
FROM TBL_T_ClassCoverage CC
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[TBL_M_District] D ON CC.DistrictId = D.DistrictId
WHERE CC.IsActive = 1 
GROUP BY CC.DistrictId, D.DistrictName
ORDER BY DistrictId ASC
```